# Asp.Net MVC Identity with External Login does not save anything in AspNetUserLogins table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

If I create a brand new Asp.Net MVC project, I do not have any problem. However, I have another project, MVC5, that is acting weird with External login (Oauth). The Async, or the normal method return that the login has been successfully added but if I go into the database, I notice that nothing is inside the table `AspNetUserLogins`. Nevertheless, I know that UserManager is correctly setup because it adds the information into `AspNetUsers`.

[image]

Why does the Identity UserManager does not save the UserLogins information when using external login (oauth) ?

Comment: Hi Pat - Did you find a reason for this? I have got the same thing when deriving my context from IdentityDbContext<AppUser>. The async methods return saying their are no errors, but no rows. Changed the UserManager.UserValidator so AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false but still no luck. Any pointers?

Comment: I have not find a solution yet. I have passed to something else and will come back to this issue in few.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Whether we had exactly the same cause of problem is hard to tell, but I found in the end that once my DbContext inherited directly from IdentityDbContext<T> as opposed to a custom base class, that in turn inherited from IdentityDbContext<T> it all seemed to start working. Maybe some sort of type checking it does under the covers. Anyway, maybe this could help you so thought i'd share.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing that might block the save is the UserValidator, all of the user manager methods call Update(user) underneath the covers which triggers a call to the UserValidator., which might be what's blocking the Save from your perspective.  Typically something like user name validation might be causing the save from being blocked.